# Unable to extract field from <span> using Beautiful Soup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have to extract the fields "Company Name", "Company Type" from the HTML page. I have been able to extract the company name using the following piece of code :

```
ol1 = soup.find('ol')
company_box = soup.find_all('span', attrs= {'class': 'company-name'})
for ol in ol1:
    for c in company_box:
        print c.text
```

I want to extract the company type too. The condition being if "company-type" is "Private", print "yes" else print "no".

While trying to do this, every single time I managed to extract the company type, it returns an empty field. The code block is:

```
for c in company_box:
    print c.text
    ptype_box = soup.find_all('span', attrs= {'class': 'company-type'})
    print ptype_box
```

The base website is fortune.com/best-companies. Please help !

Comment: Looking at your sample page, there is no `company-type` anywhere in the page view-source:http://fortune.com/best-companies/

Comment: `company-type` is found after expanding the whole list. The issue would be that bs4 is not being passed the full site.

Answer (score 1):

We can not get company-type as  element. In this site data is passed and filled by javascript dynamically. so when we try to access company-type, it will empty.

In this case, website is storing this json data in variable. so we can get that json data parse it with json.loads() python function and get all the required data ( i.e. company name and type ).

I have written code for getting company-name and company-type. Also There are lots of other information available in json variable to look upon. Hope you find it helpful.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

r = requests.get('http://fortune.com/best-companies/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
data = soup.find_all("script")[-7].string
data = data[39:-12]
d = json.loads(data)

filterd_data = d['bootstrap']['franchise']['filtered_sorted_data']

d = {}
for i in range(100):
    company_data = filterd_data[i]['companies'][0]
    company_type = company_data['type']
    company_name = company_data['term']['name']
    d[company_name] = company_type

print d
```